# Fastest way to see added, removed, and changed Objects (not primitives) between two arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a completely manual, ugly way to find all added, removed, and changed Objects (not primitives) between two arrays, and I'm wondering if there is a faster, more efficient way to accomplish this same thing. Any libraries that accomplish this?  the lodash `difference` function tells me all differences rather than which ones have been added and which have changed, so it doesn't do what I need.

Here is my code.  It works, and i want to do exactly this, just the most efficient way available:

```
    let previousState = state[0]; //<-- an array of object literals
    let currentState = state[1]; //<-- an array of object literals

    let added = [];
    let removed = [];
    let edited = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < previousState.length; i++){
        let old = previousState[i];
        let current = currentState.find(x => x.id === old.id);
        if(!current){
            removed.push(current);
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < currentState.length; i++){
        let current = currentState[i];
        let old = previousState.find(x => x.id === current.id);
        if(!old){
            added.push(current);
            continue;
        }
        if(!_.isEqual(current, old)){ //<-- this is the lodash .isEqual function
            edited.push(current);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I measured this is a bit more than twice as fast as the original algorithm.

```
let control = {};
state[0].forEach(s => {
  control[s.id] = s;
});

let added = [];
let edited = [];

state[1].forEach(s => {
  if (control[s.id]) {
    if (!_.isEqual(control[s.id], s)) {
      edited.push(s); 
    }
    delete control[s.id];
  } else {
    added.push(s);
  }
});

let removed = Object.values(control);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily faster in execution time, but it does make it a little more "functional". Hopefully this helps.

```js
// You just need to rename the "a" and "b" variables to your variable names where "a" is the original array and "b" is the array that you're comparing to it.
const a = [{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' }];
const b = [{ id: 1, name: 'abc' }, { id: 3, name: 'c' }];

const removedFromA = _.differenceBy(a, b, 'id');
const addedToA = _.differenceBy(b, a, 'id');
const changedInA = _.chain(a)
 .reject((v) => _.find(removedFromA, { id: v.id }) || _.find(addedToA, { id: v.id }))
  .reject((v) => _.chain(b).find({ id: v.id }).isEqual(v).value())
  .value();

console.log('Removed From A: ', removedFromA);
console.log('Added To A: ', addedToA);
console.log('Changed In A: ', changedInA);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```